# Magento Grouped Products With Tier Pricing

Tags: magento-1.7, tierprice

I've created a group product with two simple products.Each simple product has tier pricing.For example,

```
Simple product -1: tier pricing : Qty   Price
                                   2     100
                                   3      75
                                   5      60

Simple product -2: tier pricing:  Qty   Price
                                   2     110
                                   3      80


<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_items): ?> 
        <?php $_items->setData('tier_price',null); ?>
        <?php $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices($_items); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_tierPrices as $key => $value): ?>
                <th><?php echo $value['price_qty']; ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above code returns all the qty `2 3 5 2 3`.How do I remove the repeated "qty" values and show only unique values?

Comment: PHP's `array_unique()` function should do the trick. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php . Alternatively `array_count_values()` could be used. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Were you only wanting to display the quantities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pspahn's comment is correct. `array_unique()` will remove the duplicates.  In your code example, it could be used like this:

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php $qtys = array(); 
          foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_items): ?> 
        <?php $_items->setData('tier_price',null); ?>
        <?php $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices($_items); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_tierPrices as $key => $value): ?>
                <?php $qtys[] = $value['price_qty']; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach;
          array_unique($qtys); ?>
    <?php for ($i=0;$i<count($qtys);$i++): ?>
        <th><?php echo $qtys[$i]; ?></th>
    <?php endfor; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will output `2 3 5` based on your example.

Were you just wanting to display the quantities only like this?