# Can Magento show quantity price breaks as per example link

Tags: magento-1.9

The below link shows a category of General, then on the page shows the sub categories highlighted in red. 
I am especially interested in being able to show Quantity price breaks against each pruoduct.
http://www.aaapackaging.com.au/packaging-tape-c-3_17.html

I am brand new to Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything is possible with magento with customization.  But, yes, to an extent you can get similar results using tier prices which you can define in the admin.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

I also think grouped products might be of interest for you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-grouped-product

There's also this older thread about applying tier pricing to group products with some custom coding:

[Magento Grouped Products With Tier Pricing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/magento-grouped-products-with-tier-pricing)